# Cannot load layout or phtml not detected

Tags: php, magento

well, i don't now what is the problem is. but it seem like i cannot load layout or phtml.
this is my code

config.xml

```
 <modules>
    <Email_Rent><!-- code/local/Email/Rent-->
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Email_Rent>
 </modules>
 <global>
     <!-- Declare block class -->
     <blocks>
         <rent><!-- route -->
              <class>Email_Rent_Block</class>
         </rent>
      </blocks>

</global>

 <frontend>
   <routers>
      <rent>
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>Email_Rent</module>
             <frontName>rent</frontName>
          </args>
       </rent>
   </routers>
   <!-- declare layout for block -->
   <layout>
       <updates>
            <rent><!-- route -->
                 <file>rent.xml</file>
             </rent>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

this is rent.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<rent_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="rent/indexblock"  name="form_rent_block" template="rent/rent_form.phtml" />
    </reference>
</rent_index_index>
```

i already put `var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->getHandles());`

in my index controller. and it print out "rent_index_index"

indexcontroller.php

```
class Email_Rent_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function IndexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        //echo 'test index';
    }
    public function saveAction()
    {
        //getrequest->getpost is same as $_request/$_get/$_post function
        // get data from afficher.phtml same as View  
        $name = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('name'); //textfield nom
        $email = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('email'); //textfield prenom
        $telephone = ''.$this->getRequest()->getPost('telephone'); //textfield telephone
        //if all textfield is been filled
        if(isset($name)&&($name!='') && isset($email)&&($email!='') && isset($telephone)&&($telephone!='') )
        {
            //save data / insert sql
            $contact = Mage::getModel('test/test');
            $contact->setData('name', $name);
            $contact->setData('email', $email);
            $contact->setData('telephone', $telephone);
            $contact->save();
        }
        //on redirige l’utilisateur vers la méthode index du controller indexController
        //de notre module <strong>test</strong>
        $this->_redirect('index.php/test');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add this in your controller action

```
 $this->loadLayout();  
 $this->renderLayout();
```

This code should be inside your index controller.

Comment: i already put that in the controller. but the main container is not appear.
http://strollerworld.optimastg.com/index.php/rent/

Comment: done. i think there is no problem with my controller.

Comment: was it cache issue??

Comment: well, i already flush magento cashe so many times. but it seems not take any effect.

Comment: nope , still not working . no idea how to repair it. im still searching on other forum.

Comment: <block type="core/template"  name="form_rent_block" template="rent/rent_form.phtml" /> can u add this in your rent.xml and try

Comment: hahah . thanks dude ! thank you very much
work like a charm. hahhaa.